# CSS Spec for element and own attribute without space

Tags: css

What is the difference of the following styles with regards to spec?

```
  ul .active { background: #E7F3EF;}
  ul li.active { background: #E7F3EF;}


<ul>
  <li class="active">Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

the last one i mistakenly coded in sass as `ul li .active` and took me sometime to figure out.

Comment: Have you tried reading the actual spec? You will benefit much more from reading it than from reading an answer here.

Comment: I am not sure of an exact keyword and where in the spec i should start. It will took me more time to find the keyword "Descendant combinators" in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ul .active { background: #E7F3EF;}
```

This one will match any element with the class name "active" that is a descendant of a `ul` element.

```
ul li.active { background: #E7F3EF;}
```

This one will match any `li` element with the class name "active" that is a descendant of a `ul` element.

```
ul li .active { background: #E7F3EF;}
```

This one would match any element with the class name "active" that is a descendant of an `li` element, that is a descendant of a `ul` element.

As you have noticed, the whitespace is relevant. Whitespace in a selector often indicates a descendant combinator.

For the relevant part of the spec, see "[Descendant combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators)".